# Непонимание с представлением чисел

Tags: python

Я создаю в Python Shell файл с таким кодом:

```
from numpy import float96
from decimal import Decimal
import math

q=10; N=10
uu = (math.log(10**q+((10**q)**2-1)**0.5))/9
print uu
k = ((math.e)**uu + (math.e)**(-uu))/(2.)
print k
```

Когда исполняю этот файл в окне Python Shell, то появляются необходимые мне значения:

```
2.6354442345
7.01059752803
```

НО если я этот же код копирую в командную строку Python Shell и запускаю, то получаю более точные значения:

```
>>> q=10; N=10
uu = (math.log(10**q+((10**q)**2-1)**0.5))/9
k = ((math.e)**uu + (math.e)**(-uu))/(2.)
>>> uu
2.6354442345000444
>>> k
7.010597528033946
```

Почему так происходит? Мне нужны эти разряды, которые отбрасываются при запуске файла. Как сделать так, чтобы не округлялись числа?

Answer (score 1):

Происходит округление при `print`. Все нормально.

```
>>> from numpy import float96
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> import math
>>> q=10; N=10
>>> uu = (math.log(10**q+((10**q)**2-1)**0.5))/9
>>> k = ((math.e)**uu + (math.e)**(-uu))/(2.)
>>> print uu
2.6354442345
>>> print k
7.01059752803
>>> uu
2.6354442345000444
>>> k
7.010597528033946
>>>
```

Comment: можно ли задать параметры округления?

просто получается так, что выходные данные округляются, причем не только при выводе, а и при дальнейших расчетах.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> repr(uu)
'2.6354442345000444'
>>> repr(k)
'7.010597528033946'
```

Используй `repr`. 
Можно так print repr(uu)